# Why doesn't IntelliSense always fill up in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: intellisense, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've got an issue with the intelliSense used in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012.
It doesn't seem to fill up every time.

When I try to edit existing jobs or class methods, I type the variable or class with the . (dot) or :: (double colon) I get a small blank box (about a milimeter thick and the normal width for the intelliSense box). If I continue typing after that the text doesn't fill out on the screen, but when I hit tab the first option of the intelliSense is used. So the intelliSense system works, but I just can't see those options. (Which makes me lookup every method for a class on the internet).
However whenever I make a new job or method, I do get the intelliSense box completely filled out with all the options.

Has anyone had a similar problem? (And found a solution?)

I've tried solving it with different screens, different resolutions, tried it on my client version and on the server. Other users don't seem to have this issue, so I'm assuming it's something local on my pc...

Thank you,
Lode

Comment: Have you tried changing your Windows theme?

Answer (score 0):

I've never been on this case in AX2012 but in previous versions, the IntelliSense problems were due to hidden compilation errors (there are errors, but the compiler is not showing them) or corrupted metadata (internal problems).

Some solutions where, first, compile the object where we have the problem (compile forward if it's a class). If this doesn't seems to work, run the jobs that update metadata on the AOT (they are under the Development menu), and finally, update cross-reference for the object that gives the problem (right click on the object) or in the worst case, update all cross-reference for the entire AOT (periodic job)